# what's wrong dmy_hm("3/10/2010 2:00",tz="Australia/Melbourne")?

Tags: r, lubridate

I get an error when I run these:

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hm("3/10/2010 2:00",tz="Australia/Melbourne")
dmy_hm("2/10/2011 2:00",tz="Australia/Melbourne")
```

Is it just me?

Comment: It's customary to include the error message when posting. I get no error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is daylight savings time, which started at these time points. Anything from 3/10/2010 2:00 to 3/10/2010 2:59 does not exist in this time zone.

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hm("3/10/2010 1:59",tz="Australia/Melbourne")
#[1] "2010-10-03 01:59:00 EST"
dmy_hm("3/10/2010 2:00",tz="Australia/Melbourne")
#Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
#Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
dmy_hm("3/10/2010 2:01",tz="Australia/Melbourne")
#Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
#Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
dmy_hm("3/10/2010 2:59",tz="Australia/Melbourne")
#Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
#Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
dmy_hm("3/10/2010 3:00",tz="Australia/Melbourne")
#[1] "2010-10-03 03:00:00 EST"
```

However, lubridate should handle this gracefully, e.g., return `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

I get the error

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Using `traceback()`, the call stack when the error occured looks like this

```
...
10: .local_parse(x[new_na])
9: .local_parse(x[new_na])
8: .local_parse(x[new_na])
7: .local_parse(x[new_na])
6: .local_parse(x[new_na])
5: .local_parse(x[to_parse], TRUE)
4: parse_date_time(dates, orders, tz = tz, locale = locale, quiet = quiet)
3: as.POSIXct(parse_date_time(dates, orders, tz = tz, locale = locale, 
     ...
2: .parse_xxx_hms(..., orders = "dmyR", quiet = quiet, tz = tz, 
     ...
1: dmy_hm("2/10/2011 2:00", tz = "Australia/Melbourne")
```

So it's a bug in `.local_parse`, which is defined inside `parse_date_time`.  You can submit a bug report here:

https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues

Comment: @Roland I take it you are both on Windows? At home on Mac this did not return an error, but at work on Win7 I get the same error. It seems OS specific.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Yes, I'm running Win7, but the problem may be specific to the version of `lubridate`.  `packageVersion("lubridate")` returns `1.3.1` for me.  Is that the case on your Mac machine?

Comment: @RichieCotton I'm `1.3.0` on W7, and I'm not sure for Mac (I left it at home). I'll check later, but I'm willing to be its older as I haven't updated for a while.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Put `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` in your `Rprofile.site` file. :)

Comment: And it's [fixed](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/commit/954ff9c66df52bf2f219870057f99fa7df17c483) already.

Comment: @Roland Ok, so it's fixed? Is it released in the latest version? I tried v1.3.3 and still gets the same error

Comment: @qoheleth It's fixed in the development branch on github (which you could install). It will probably be fixed in one of the future versions on CRAN. Btw., personally I don't use lubridate. `as.POSIXct` does the job just fine (and without this error). However, if you have these times in your data, you should probably use a timezone without daylight savings.